# how to make a treeview with a database

Tags: java, html, sql, database, treeview

I was wondering how to make a treeview in my java code. the tree must show project, and the subproject and task all comming from my SQL database, i have three tables.

I am kind of unsure the best approache, do I make a tree in HTML and then get the data with thymeleaf or do I Create a tree in mysql?

Hope someone can help me:)

best regards Emma

Comment: You have a choice of many ways to build a web app in Java. This site is not for general guidance. For that, try a forums site such as JavaRanch.com. For specific software recommendations, search the sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

A best practice is to use the appropriate tool. SQL database is good at selecting, joining, sorting, and producing tabular data. Java and especially Thymeleaf are good for transforming, formating data, templating, and generating web content.